# Is it worthwhile to include a large C++ library if I only need several functions from it?

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries

I have a question related to C++ static library and dynamic library. Suppose now you are developing a program, and one functionality can be found in a C++ library. Then you have two choices: one is to write some codes (suppose not too many) and re-implement the function; the other is to invoke the function from the C++ library. However, the C++ library you want to use is a very big one while you only use a very small part of the library. In this case, what is a better choice? Thanks!

Comment: i am developing a simple line drawing program and i am using gdi-plus. i dont need to re-invent the wheel. But i like knowing the basics so i dig deeper till assembler. So, if it is time, use already invented thing. İf it is space, invent only the thing you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- static library linking will only link your executable with the symbols you effectively use.
  say you have 200 functions in the lib and use only 4 (including inner calls of the lib), then only the 4 symbols you used will be linked in the executable. so linking with a 2Mb lib may result adding only 20k to your executable.
- dynamic libraries under windows should be symbol complete , ie, the DLL will contain the 200 symbols wether you need only 4. while it won't have a big impact on your executable size (since the lib used to link with the DLL is only a symbol forwarder) , it may impact load time & memory footprint.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know, if someone could give the "right" answer here. I think it's more like a personal choice.

If the library is really big and I need, let's say 2-3 functions from it, I'd totally avoid using the library and implement them (or copy the implementation, if the license allows this).

For example, several times I needed some functions for parsing string in some way. Boost has such functions. But I didn't want to add a dependency to Boost in my project, just because of 2-3 functions, 20-50 rows code. I just reimplemented them by myself.

But, as I already said, it's more like a personal choice. Or depends on the restrictions, if you have such.

---

**EDIT:** NOTE: you don't need to "re-invent the wheel". **If you need a lot of things** from this library, just use it! Don't try to implement something, that already exists (as it's already tested and used by other users). Especially if it's complicated.

Comment: +1, but I'd be careful about making assumptions about the amount of testing that's gone into someone else library, unless it's widely used and understood.

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin - correct! This should always be in developer's mind, when using 3rd party library.

Answer (score 2):

Use the library, if the compiling overhead every becomes a problem (which it doesn't for most projects), re\implementing it then would be trivial. While for now you don't have to spend the time to write that extra code, throwing in the `#include` is much faster and less worrisome.

Answer (score 1):

If the library is a shared library that is already installed on the system you wish to deploy on, there is only a tiny overhead in using it - both in terms of linking and at run-time.

If however need to deploy the library in question,  the possibility of static linking might be worth investigating.

Either case is preferable to writing your own implementation of the features used.  The library version is proven and yours probably isn't.

Answer (score 1):

This is very subjective, a lot of factors play a role that you didn't document.  Like: are you still going to support this program 10 years from now?  That's almost a sure-fire Yes on C++ code these days.  Good odds that you'll regret not being able to easily keep up with maintenance releases of the library, copy/pasting that code is going to get old and whomever takes over maintenance some day will definitely not enjoy this if you don't carefully document what you did.

Then there's the premature optimization angle.  A loaded executable image on Windows requires very few resources.  A "large" library is, say, 10 megabytes of code.  That's 0.5% of the virtual memory address space in a 32-bit process.  With focus on *virtual*, you don't pay for code you don't use.  A very nice benefit of a demand-paged operating system.  It's pretty difficult to justify spending any decent amount of time on hacking the library and documenting what you did when *measurable* benefits of doing so are small.  Only you can make that cost/benefit analysis.

Answer (score 0):

If the include file for that library is very large, use forward declaration.

If the linking is the problem consider shared libraries (perhaps just for development).

If the linking is the problem and those functions are trivial perhaps consider coding them yourself.

Otherwise just take the hit.